# function domain/range problem

Tags: functions

I'm trying to answer this question from a text but I don't like any of the answer choices:

[image: book question]

For those who cannot see the graph, the function can be expressed as

$$
y     = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            -\frac{3}{4}x - 3 & \quad x \lt 4 \\
            \frac{3}{4}x - 6  & \quad x \ge 4 
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

I graphed it and solved in analytically and my answer is that:

[image: my solution]

For $x < -6,$ the new piecewise function is undefined;

for $-6 \leq x \leq -3,$ the function is defined;

for $x > -3$ the function is undefined as it does not pass the vertical line test.

My answer does not even have the same intervals as the book answer.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: What about the horizontal line test on x- interval $(0,4)$?

Comment: I believe it is asking you to find a restriction to the domain for the graphed function such that it has an inverse.  Use the *horizontal* line test to figure it out.

Comment: If I ask it to pass the horizontal line test (thus passing both the Vline and Hline test so it's one-to-one) , don't I get the same restrictions that I calculated above?  i.e. less than -6 undefined, between -6 and -3 passes test, greater than -3 doesn't pass the line test?